# Check if a word is within various sub-intervals of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax-error

I have an array of words (25 of them, 0-24) and I want to do tests in a for loop that checks whether the randomly chosen word is within the interval 0-4, 5-9, 10-14 etc..

How do I do this?

```
else if (words[i > 4 && <= 9]){}
```

I tried that line in a `for` loop, but it gives me a syntax error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <=
```

Comment: I'm trying to check if the i is any of the numbers 5,6,7,8 or 9.
Sorry, badly written. 

I'm making a hangman game, and if `words[i]` is in any of those positions, I want to write the line: `document.getElementById("showHint").innerHTML = "Hint: A field of study";`

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you're asking. That's preferable over adding comments. Thanks!

Comment: Your question suffers from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you are describing your error, but not the actual problem you are trying to solve.  We can only help if we know the objective and we will ALWAYS be able to offer better help if we know exactly what you're trying to accomplish (not just the current error you are facing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a left comparison in your condition. Use this as a condition:

```
i > 4 && i <= 9
```

However, note that you're not doing anything useful with the condition. Your result will be akin to `words[true]` or `words[false]`.

***Update***

You've now elaborated a little more. If I understand you correctly, you want to pick a random word from your array, and then work out which interval of 5 it resides at within the array.

In the below example, the interval is indexed; so 0 = 0-4, 1 = 5-9, 2 = 10-14 and so on...

```js
var words = [ "Synergetic", "unsteeped", "goldcup", "coronach", "swamper", "rehearse", "rusty", "reannotation", "dunne", "unblenched", "classification", "interpolation", "toper", "grisliest.", "Rechart", "imbower", "reilluminating", "glucagon", "interassuring", "parallelepipedon", "doyenne", "neenah", "tetragram" ];

function pickARandomWordAndCheckTheInterval(){
  
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);

  var word = words[randomIndex]
  var interval = Math.floor(randomIndex / 5);
  
  console.log('The random word is:' + word);
  console.log('The interval is:' + interval );
  
}

pickARandomWordAndCheckTheInterval();
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman He specified an interest in testing the numbers 5,6,7,8 or 9. I don't presume to know why he would use true/false to index an array/object. Don't think a downvote is necessary.

Comment: This helps me shennan, it's late here and I'm tired.. Sorry for asking silly questions. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnKugelman Before he edited his comment, it simply read: "I'm trying to check if the i is any of the numbers 5,6,7,8 or 9". That was a green light for me. I'm not saying it's the definitive answer, but I do think it adds something.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for removing all your comments and therefore all the context of our conversation.

Answer (score -1):

To explain it really really simple way you just forgotten to tell the language what needs to be less than or equal 9.

You assumed it processes logic condition like humans do (we would assume that after && operator you're still thinking about i, but that's not what JS interpreter would do).

What comes after && needs to be an expression that can be evaluated. `<= 9` doesn't evaluate to value (it is not treated as valid expression because `<=` is kind of binary operator which requires two operands, one before and one after).

For JS interpreter it just means "less than or equal to 9". But what is "less than or equal to 9"? You need to tell it "i is less than or equal to 9".

`i > 4 && i <= 9` is the correct way to write that.

Comment: This is a nice elaboration on @shennan's answer, but it has the same problem of not being a complete answer. I would love to upvote this if you could address his true underlying question (which may involve getting him to explain it better).

Comment: I find this elaboration fine and pretty precise for the question. The problem is that author of the question is still shaping the explanation of what he actually wants to achieve. And despite real background (that is yet to be uncovered) he actually made a mistake I was writing about :) And as someone else already noticed too, I don't think downvote is necessary for answer. It simply smells like pseudo-academic pickiness. You'd better downvote the question.

Comment: Question was clear: "I tried that line in a for loop, but it gives me a syntax error." And I gave explanation about why it is so.